# Is it possible to forego creating an EOA with social logins and directly create a smart wallet with Safe?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core

I have two questions:

1- Is it possible to forego creating an EOA with social logins (i.e., "Sign in with Google") and directly create a smart wallet? Currently, I believe we first need to create an EOA with social logins (via Auth kit) and then create a Safe. (via Protocol kit).

2- Whether this is doable or not, Does Safe support counterfactual deployments? Meaning that we could precompute a smart contract wallet address before deploying it and be able to send funds to it.

Here is one common scenario which we need counterfactual deployments for:

> Let's say we have a user in our wallet, we want to create multiple
> smart wallets (on Mainnet, Optimism, etc) on Safe for this user but we don't want to deploy any
> wallets before there's any activity on it to avoid costs. This is why we're looking at
> counterfactual deployments. We want to know the Safe wallet addresses
> before "deploying" them but deploying them only when the user tries to
> receive or send funds with it. (Again mainly to avoid unnecessary
> costs)

Answer (score 0):

1. As of now, this is not possible, you need to do both in separate actions using the SDK.
2. Yes, you can use Safe{Core} SDK protocol kit [`create`](https://docs.safe.global/sdk-protocol-kit/reference/safe#create) method to generate the address of a Safe and then deploy it later using [`deploySafe`](https://docs.safe.global/sdk-protocol-kit/reference/safe-factory#deploysafe). You can use most of the methods from the protocol kit on this counterfactual safe, as if it was deployed. Be aware that when you deploy it, the `safeAccountConfig` must be **exactly** the same as it would result in the safe being deployed at a different address otherwise.